# Run (deploy?) a "maven" .war in TOMCAT 8

Tags: maven, tomcat, tomcat8, maven-tomcat-plugin

First of all i don't have a clue about Maven, nor Tomcat, nor Java.

I have a .war file with a webpage and a Tomcat 8 server installed in a Mac (Yosemite). Is located at `/Library/Tomcat/webapps/wm-admin-ui.war`.
I also have Maven (v3) installed and configured with a tomcat user.

I need to run the .war in a Tomcat server that apparently is intended to be deployed by some Maven plugin. I figured this out because there's a `maven` directory at META-INF and the usual deployment doesn't work at all. See picture below as reference.

Thing is,

- How do I install the maven plugin in tomcat 8? (I've already checked google)
- Is "deploy" a synonym of "run"?

Directory structure of '/Library/Tomcat/webapps/wm-admin-ui' :

[image]

The errors at the catalina.out log:

```
11-Aug-2015 10:23:43.128 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars Al menos un JAR, que se ha explorado buscando TLDs, aún no contenía TLDs. Activar historial de depuración para este historiador para una completa lista de los JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se halló TLDs. Saltarse JARs no necesarios durante la exploración puede dar lugar a una mejora de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilación de JSP .
11-Aug-2015 10:23:43.360 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/wm-admin-ui]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at com.toro.wm.configurations.WmWebApplicationInitializer.getSwaggerBasePath(WmWebApplicationInitializer.java:86)
    at com.toro.wm.configurations.WmWebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(WmWebApplicationInitializer.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

11-Aug-2015 10:23:43.362 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error durante el despliegue del archivo /Users/r01010010/Develop/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/wm-admin-ui.war de la aplicación web
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/wm-admin-ui]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the code that throughs the error:

```
private String getSwaggerBasePath() {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/swagger.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(is);
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to handle stream for swagger.properties file ", e);
    }

    String context = properties.getProperty("swagger.base_path", "");

    return (StringUtils.isEmpty(context) ? "" : context) + "/wm-admin-ui/rest";
}
```

Comment: Any error when Tomcat starts ? If yes show us.

Comment: It seems u r looking for [How to deploy Maven based war file to Tomcat](https://www.google.com/search?q=java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=How+to+deploy+Maven+based+war+file+to+Tomcat)

Comment: I already looked for it but it takes for granted that I know many things about such an environment. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @PawełGłowacz yes, I add them to the post

Comment: It seems that class `com.toro.wm.configurations.WmWebApplicationInitializer` with method `getSwaggerBasePath` has problem with load some property file. Check this line in this class `WmWebApplicationInitializer.java:86`. Seems you havent deployed crucial file and when application initialize context it demands that file.

Comment: Along with the .war they gave me a zip with `*.properties` files but i don't know what to do with them

Comment: I updated the question with the code

Comment: Put all your properties in WEB-INF/classes and give a shot

Comment: YEP, now it works THANK YOU!

Comment: I will put an answer. So please mark as answered. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that class `com.toro.wm.configurations.WmWebApplicationInitializer` with method `getSwaggerBasePath` has problem with load some property file.

Check this line in this class `WmWebApplicationInitializer.java:86`. Seems you haven't deployed crucial file and when application initialize context it demands that file.

Second problem is you need to put all properties in path `WEB-INF/classes`.

Now all should work.

Comment: Yep, it was exactly that.